# Checking on the click of next button whether the user has entered a value in textbox

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to know how do I validate the entry in the textbox? I am making use of the wix toolset 3.5. What I mean is I should get a prompt or some message that says that you must enter the text (I have a name of the person here ) and the installation must not proceed without it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your UI element so that there is a conditional Publish tag that determines if the property attached to the TextBox is populated or not:

```
  <Publish Dialog="NameSettingsDlg" 
           Control="Next" 
           Property="ErrorMessage" Value="You need to fill in your name!" 
           Order="1">
      NOT NAME_PROPERTY
  </Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="NameSettingsDlg" 
           Control="Next" 
           Event="SpawnDialog" 
           Value="InvalidSettingsDlg" 
           Order="2">
      NOT NAME_PROPERTY
  </Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="NameSettingsDlg" 
           Control="Next" 
           Event="NewDialog" 
           Value="VerifyReadyDlg">
  </Publish>
```

where the "InvalidSettingsDlg" is defined as:

```
<Fragment>
    <UI>
        <Dialog Id="InvalidSettingsDlg" 
                Width="260" 
                Height="85" 
                Title="!(loc.InvalidSettingsDlg_Title)">
            <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="102" Y="57" Width="56" 
                     Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)">
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Text" Type="Text" X="48" Y="22" Width="194" Height="30" 
                     Text="[ErrorMessage]" />
            <Control Id="Icon" Type="Icon" X="15" Y="15" Width="24" Height="24" 
                     ToolTip="!(loc.InvalidSettingsDlgIconTooltip)" FixedSize="yes"
                     IconSize="32" Text="WixUI_Ico_Exclam" />
         </Dialog>
    </UI>
</Fragment>
```